# Why mongodb doesn't delete document every 30 seconds?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, typegoose

I have a problem with implementing TTL with typegoose for mongodb..
Basically I want to delete a document from the collection if it's older than 30 seconds.

```
@ObjectType("TokenResetPasswordType")
@InputType("TokenResetPasswordInput")
@index(
   { createdAt: -1, confirmed: 1 },
   { expireAfterSeconds: 30, partialFilterExpression: { confirmed: false } }
)
export class TokenResetPassword {
    @Field()
    @Property({ lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Field(() => [User], { nullable: true })
    @Property({ ref: "User", default: "" })
    user?: Ref<User>;

    @prop({ default: Date.now, index: true })
    createdAt?: Date;
}
```

Comment: Please share some more code. There is nothing we can do with your question right now.

Comment: check the actual index stored in MongoDB.  If the collection and index already exist when the code is run, mongoose will _not_ drop and recreate the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/

> TTL indexes are special ***single-field indexes*** that MongoDB can use to automatically remove documents from a collection after a certain amount of time or at a specific clock time.

You need to create an `expireAfterSeconds` index for the `createdAt` field alone, not for two fields at once.

Also note:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#timing-of-the-delete-operation

> ### Timing of the Delete Operation
>
> The TTL index does not guarantee that expired data will be deleted immediately upon expiration. There may be a delay between the time a document expires and the time that MongoDB removes the document from the database.
>
> The background task that removes expired documents runs **every 60 seconds.** As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the period between the expiration of the document and the running of the background task.
>
> Because the duration of the removal operation depends on the workload of your mongod instance, **expired data may exist for some time beyond the 60 second period** between runs of the background task.

Comment: I waited 10 minutes and the data is still there

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the record from monogoDB, this is how you need to create the schema:

You need to add **`index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 })`** in your code while d efiningschema as below.

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ timestamps: true, versionKey: false })
export class OTP extends Document {

 @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
 otp: string;

 @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
 referenceNo: string;


 @Prop({ type: Date, expires: 300 }) // 300 seconds = 5 minutes
 expiresAt: Date;
}

export const OTPSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(OTP).index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });
```

**This will delete your record after 300 seconds once created.**